# I want to remove a first text on the cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram-bot

I want to remove "/input " before the other text.
I use this code

```
else if(text.startsWith("/input")) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("inputan");
    var item = text.split(",");
    sheet.appendRow([date,id,name,item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3]]);
    sendText(id,"Thanks " + name + " data has been recorded");
  }
```

For the text, I use code

```
var text = data.message.text;
```

I have tried to edit 'var text' but the other command come error
also I tried to separate the item, but only input number 1 comma 2 comma and 2,3, and 4 entered the table

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75197818/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to remove "/input " before the other text

Use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), like this:

```js
  const text = String(data.message.text).replace(/\/input /i, '');
```